# /me/feed in facebook graph api has first comment of wallpost as separate status entry

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

when getting my feed with */me/feed* it seems that the first comment on posts of other users on my wall is represented another time in the feed as an independent status entry (also has a different id) itself.

It looks like the following JSON output. The first entry of the list is apparently generated from the first comment of the second entry of the list.

I could not reproduce the problem, another post on my wall I commented on turned out normal (= no duplicate entry for first comment)

Is this a bug in Facebook itself or can someone explain this behavior?

```
[
{
  "id": "someID_4300357461829", 
  "from": {
    "name": "user1", 
    "id": "someID"
  }, 
  "story": "\"na oida\" on user2's post on your wall.", 
  "story_tags": {
    "13": [
      {
        "id": "someID2", 
        "name": "user2", 
        "offset": 13, 
        "length": 15, 
        "type": "user"
      }
    ]
  }, 
  "type": "status", 
  "created_time": "2012-11-03T01:41:15+0000", 
  "updated_time": "2012-11-03T01:41:15+0000", 
  "comments": {
    "count": 0
  }
}, 
{
  "id": "someID_4300356661809", 
  "from": {
    "name": "user2", 
    "id": "someID2"
  }, 
  "to": {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "user1", 
        "id": "someID"
      }
    ]
  }, 
  "message": "hi!", 
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "Comment", 
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/someID/posts/4300356661809"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Like", 
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/someID/posts/4300356661809"
    }
  ], 
  "type": "status", 
  "created_time": "2012-11-03T01:40:54+0000", 
  "updated_time": "2012-11-03T01:45:21+0000", 
  "comments": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "someID_4300356661809_4479943", 
        "from": {
          "name": "user1", 
          "id": "someID"
        }, 
        "message": "na oida", 
        "created_time": "2012-11-03T01:41:15+0000"
      }, 
      {
        "id": "someID_4300356661809_4479949", 
        "from": {
          "name": "user1", 
          "id": "someID"
        }, 
        "message": "interesting", 
        "created_time": "2012-11-03T01:42:31+0000"
      }, 
      {
        "id": "someID_4300356661809_4479956", 
        "from": {
          "name": "user1", 
          "id": "someID"
        }, 
        "message": "another one", 
        "created_time": "2012-11-03T01:44:40+0000"
      }, 
      {
        "id": "someID_4300356661809_4479959", 
        "from": {
          "name": "user2", 
          "id": "someID3"
        }, 
        "message": "spam", 
        "created_time": "2012-11-03T01:45:21+0000"
      }
    ], 
    "count": 4
  }
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. I've submitted a bug to facebook. Vote it up - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/483624361705934

Comment: Any advance on this issue. I am having the same problem and it is very annoying!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you haven't realised, those "wrong" posts doesn't have any action in it, so you can filter the right posts just checking if actions exist.